# Android Switch dosent show in ViewGroup

Tags: android, uiswitch, android-viewgroup

I want to create a Widget like this :

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTsNt.png)

But, what is shown is this:

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjuKd.png)

Why this `Switch` `Button` doesn't show in `ViewGroup`:

In this case just `Switch`'s text `"hello"` is showing.

```
public class TestView extends ViewGroup {
   ...
   private void init() {
       imageView = new ImageView(getContext());
       imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.clock_icon);

       aSwitch = new Switch(getContext());
       aSwitch.setText("hello");
       aSwitch.setChecked(true);

       addView(imageView);
       addView(aSwitch);

   }

   @Override
   protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
       super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
       imageView.layout(0, 50,100, 70);
       aSwitch.layout(50,50,100,70);
   }
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tnx @Gugalo  I solved that  with your descriptions.

```
 @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        aSwitch.measure(w,h);
        aSwitch.layout(0, 0,  aSwitch.getMeasuredWidth(), aSwitch.getMeasuredHeight());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to create a resource file for the layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/clock_icon"/>
    <Switch
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:checked="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then inflate it programatically when needed:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_resource_file, container, false);
}
```

Comment: thank you @Charlie but I want to create it by programming.

Answer (score 0):

I am not confident that `ViewGroup.layout(int l, int t, int r, int b)` is correct approuch to define size and position of a view, since this method is only part of overall flow of drawing view:

> `ViewGroup.layout(int l, int t, int r, int b)` is the second phase of the layout mechanism. (The first is measuring) 
>   https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#layout(int, int, int, int)

But anyways, you can try to call `View.requestLayout()`. Call this when something has changed which has invalidated the layout of this view.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout()

The only problem is that, for some reason, it will not work from `View.onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)` so you will have to do something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    imageView.layout(0, 50,100, 70);
    aSwitch.layout(50,50,100,70);
    post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            imageView.requestLayout();
            aSwitch.requestLayout();
        }
    });
}
```